# Special cases of the Rohrlich-Lang conjecture with Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

The Gamma function satisfies:

$$\Gamma(z + 1) = z\Gamma(z)$$
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1 - z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$
$$\prod_{k = 0}^{n-1}\Gamma\left(a+\frac{k}{n}\right) = (2\pi)^{(n-1)/2}n^{-na + 1/2}\Gamma(na)$$

> The Rohrlich conjecture states:
>
> Any multiplicative dependence relation of the form
> $$\pi^{b/2}\prod_{a \in \mathbb{Q}}\Gamma(a)^{m_a} \in \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$$
> is a consequence of the relations above.

Do we know special cases where this is valid? For instance, given rationals $a$ and $b$, do we know when $\dfrac{1}{\pi}\dfrac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a + b)}$ is algebraic? And for three rationals?

Comment: So far as I know, it is unknown whether, say, $\Gamma(1/5)$ is algebraic.

Comment: Wikipedia agrees with me, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#General_rational_arguments so I suspect very, very little is known about your question.

Comment: Hossein likes this post. Regards!

Comment: Lang strengthened it from monomial to polynomial relations.